# Creating a constructor for retrieving data in Json Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make this more organized, and for some reason I can't wrap my head around how I would make it where I don't have the controller preparing the data.

I have been always under the impression that it's better practice to have the model prepare it for me.

How could I achieve that?

Course Controller:

```
public class CoursesController : Controller
{
    private readonly CourseVmContext db = new CourseVmContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Data = db.CourseVms.ToList().AsEnumerable();
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string JsonData = serializer.Serialize(Data);

        return View(JsonData);
    }
}
```

Course View Model:

```
    public class CourseVm
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instructor { get; set; }
}

public class CourseVmContext : DbContext
{
    public CourseVmContext()
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }
    public DbSet<CourseVm> CourseVms { get; set; }  
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: What are you doing with the value of `bradyOutput`? You don't seem to be using it anywhere.

Comment: are you trying to create a controller that returns `json`?

Comment: I'm sorry Stephan, I thought I changed the name to that.. It's correct now.

Jossef, Yes, that's exactly my plan. But I was hoping I could get the ViewModel to give the model to the controller in Json.

Comment: Normally you return a model to a view so you can render its properties `return View(model)`, or you return a JsonResult of the model `return Json(model);` that might be used in an ajax callback. How are you intending to use this?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense when you put it that way. Because Knowing later in this project I may need to grab a particular set of that data and so forth... But right now I am using AngularJs in my actual view. Here is a link where I implement it. http://pastebin.com/jkUU6Jkh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the snippet you posted in your comment:

```
registrationModule.factory("bootstrappedCourses", function() {
            return {
                courses: @Model
            };
        });
```

seems like you are bypassing the ajax capabilities of `angularjs`.

anyway, if you decide to continue this way, all you need is a `string` type model (what you did in your controller)

and in your view, you need to call `angular.fromJson()` method

```
registrationModule.factory("bootstrappedCourses", function() {
            return {
                courses: angular.fromJson("@Model")
            };
        });
```

i strongly recommend you to use alternative ways such as a `JsonResult` controller and angular's `$http` module - **[read this tutorial](http://codewala.net/2014/06/16/learning-angularjs-with-asp-net-mvc-part-4/)**

Comment: Such as actually using an Ajax call?? xD

Comment: Actually thank you for pointing that out to me... to be honest, I got so caught up in this I forgot about that feature... xD
Thank you.